# Jquery form inputs not being serialized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what I'm doing is after an AJAX call, I need to dynamically create a table row containing two hidden inputs, one regular input, and two buttons that have the same functionality as the buttons already on the page when it loads. My problem is that the form I try to serialize is empty, and I'm not sure why.

Here's how I'm generating my html:

```
function addNewPlayerRow(player, tid) {
    var html = "<tr> <form role='form' name='editplayerform'>";
    html += "<td>";
    html += "<input type='hidden' name='tournamentidform' value='" + tid + "'/>";
    html += "<input type='hidden' name='playerid' value='" + player._id + "'>";
    html += "<input type='input' class='form-control' name='playername' value='" + player.player_name + "'/>";
    html += "</td></form>";
    html += "<td>";
    html += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-success saveplayerbutton' onclick='savePlayerSender(this)'>Save Name</button>";
    html += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger deleteplayerbutton' onclick='deletePlayerSender(this)'>Remove</button>";
    html += "</tr>";
    $(html).hide().appendTo("#playersbody").fadeIn(300);
}
```

And here's the onclick function for buttons of the deleteplayerbutton class.

```
function deletePlayerSender(button) {
    var form = $(button).parent().prev().prev();
    console.log($(form));
    console.log($(form).serialize());
}
```

When I click the button, the console logs and empty serialization form. Anyone know why?

Comment: I don't believe you can stick a form tag inbetween a <tr> and a <td> tag. This is invalid html syntax.

Comment: ^ that, open the console and look at the markup the browser constructs, it's not what you think it is, and you're not getting the form, which is why it doesn't serialize

Comment: Ah, ok. That would do it. Would it make more sense to have the form at the top, then the <tr> and <td>?

Comment: You can put the form within the <td> tag.

Answer (score 0):

A simple test like:

```
console.log($(button).parent().prev().prev().tagName);
```

should reveal which element you are targeting, which at first look seems to me the <tr> element and not the form. Furthermore, as other suggested you should revisit your html structure. Note that you forgot the closing </td> before the closing </tr>

Answer (score 0):

The `button` has a reference to the `form` it belongs to:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="deletePlayerSender(this)">Remove</button> //add the type submit, which mimics the behaviour of input

var form = $(button).get(0).form; //access the DOM element using get(0)
//alternatively
var $form = $(button).parents('form'); //parents() in plural. Return the form element as jQuery element
console.log(form, $form);
console.log($(form).serialize());
console.log($form.serialize());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put html where you want,

Form element can't be placed between Table blocks which means it can only
wrap a table, or be placed within td.

Also try replace

```
.parent().prev().prev()
```

with

```
 $(button).parent().parent().find('form')
```

that will support structure changes

Working code below:

```
function addNewPlayerRow(player, tid) {
var html = "<tr>";
html += "<td><form role='form' name='editplayerform'>";
html += "<input type='hidden' name='tournamentidform' value='" + tid + "'/>";
html += "<input type='hidden' name='playerid' value='" + player._id + "'>";
html += "<input type='input' class='form-control' name='playername' value='" + player.player_name + "'/>";
html += "</form></td>";
html += "<td>";
html += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-success saveplayerbutton' onclick='savePlayerSender(this)'>Save Name</button>";
html += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger deleteplayerbutton' onclick='deletePlayerSender(this)'>Remove</button>";
html += "</tr>";
$(html).hide().appendTo("#playersbody").fadeIn(300);
}


function deletePlayerSender(button) {
var form = $(button).parent().parent().find('form');
console.log($(form));
console.log($(form).serialize());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check https://jsfiddle.net/dk7qbfpd/. I did some corrections to your code and now is working.

there are some changes in both methods, *add* and *delete*

```
function addNewPlayerRow(player, tid) 
{
    var html = "<tr><td><form role='form' name='editplayerform" + player._id + "' id='editplayerform" + player._id + "' >";
    html += "<input type='hidden' name='tournamentidform' value='" + tid + "'/>";
    html += "<input type='hidden' name='playerid' value='" + player._id + "'>";
    html += "<input type='input' class='form-control' name='playername' value='" + player.player_name + "'/>";
    html += "</form></td>";
    html += "<td>";
    html += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-success saveplayerbutton' onclick='savePlayerSender(" + player._id + ");'>Save Name</button>";
    html += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger deleteplayerbutton' onclick='deletePlayerSender(" + player._id + ");'>Remove</button>";
    html += "</td></tr>";

    $(html).hide().appendTo("#playersbody").fadeIn(300);
}

function deletePlayerSender(playerId) 
{
    var form = $("#editplayerform" + playerId);
    console.log($(form).serialize());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the help, everyone! I managed to fix it by putting the form inside the `<td>` and then finding the form starting at the button by doing this:

```
var form = $(button).parent().prev().children("form");
```